# Azure EventGrid MQTT Broker QuotaExceeded

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, mqttnet

I'm building a service which connects to the MQTT broker service in Azure Event Grid.

It was connecting ok, but now I've started getting a QuotaExceeded response/exception when I try to connect a client for publishing.  (I'm using MQTTNet, using Entra JWT authentication)

[image]

Nobody else is using it and the usage so far is minimal:
[image]

I tried increasing the the throughput units, but that changed nothing.

I've checked the quota limits outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/quotas-limits#mqtt-limits-in-namespace) and fail to see how I could be exceeding any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand the cause of the issue, changing the client id / user served as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, for me the problem is that I set up 1 session per 1 client. When I first tested with Mqtt Explorer everything worked, later that I tested from mqttnet with the same client authentication name (username) but different clientID (session-identifier) and that error happened even though I had disconnected session from mqtt explorer already. I had to wait for a while then it worked again.